# Getting textbox values in ItemDataBinding or ItemDataBound event telerik report

Tags: c#, telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

I am working on a telerik report. In my report there are three textboxes (textBox14, textBox15,textBox16).

In textBox14 and 15, showing a sum of values from data source based on sum group criteria. I want to show the sum of the textBox14 and 15 values in 16. How can I get the values of the textBox 14 and 15 in textBox16's ItemDataBinding or ItemDataBound event.

```
private void textBox16_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string amt= textBox14.Value;  // It getting only the mapped field name. ie Fields.amt, but I want the display text of the textBox14. There is no .Text property  for textBox14.

        string tax= textBox15.Value; // It getting only the mapped field name. ie Fields.tax, but I want the display text of the textBox14. There is no .Text property  for textBox15.


    }
```

I want to set the textBox16 value as

```
textBox16.Value = Convert.ToString(ConvetToInt32(amt) + ConvetToInt32(tax));
```

How can I get the values ?.

Comment: I have the same problem! did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void textBox16_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string amt = textBox14.Text;  
            string tax = textBox15.Text; 
        }
```

and then call:

```
 textBox16.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(amt) + Convert.ToInt32(tax));
```

Comment: There is no .Text property for the texbox14 and 15  :(

Comment: did you add runat="server" parameter while declaring your TextBox's : 14,15 and 16?

Comment: this is Telerik.Reporting.TextBox, There is no property for 'runat' for this text box.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try the detail_ItemDataBound event

```
private void detail_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Telerik.Reporting.Processing.DetailSection section = (sender as Telerik.Reporting.Processing.DetailSection);
    Telerik.Reporting.Processing.TextBox = (Telerik.Reporting.Processing.TextBox)Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ElementTreeHelper.GetChildByName(section, "textBox14");
    Telerik.Reporting.Processing.TextBox = (Telerik.Reporting.Processing.TextBox)Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ElementTreeHelper.GetChildByName(section, "textBox15");
    Telerik.Reporting.Processing.TextBox txtTotal = (Telerik.Reporting.Processing.TextBox)Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ElementTreeHelper.GetChildByName(section, "textBox16");
    txtTotal.Value = (Convert.ToInt32(txtAmt.Value) + Convert.ToInt32(txtTax.Value)).ToString();
}
```